# Eclipse RCP application - how to detect when application is idle?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am writing an Eclipse RCP application that will have other plugin contributions besides my own, and need to determine when the application is idle (i.e. no activity for a period of time, application is minimized, etc.), and when that changes (i.e. application is brought back to the foreground, a mouse is clicked, etc.).

The problem I'm having is that I was going to capture all application keystrokes and mouse moves/clicks...using that to reset a timer, and when the timer is hit, then some idle processing can occur (i.e. informing a server of the idleness - and then again when we switch to active - nothing intensive).  However, the application window shell does not receive child events for the various views, etc. so either I'm missing something, or this is the wrong approach.

Can anyone offer a solution?  I'm not looking for system-wide idleness - just application idleness.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that

```
    display.addFilter(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        }
    });
```

is what you're looking for (you can add other events, too)?

This is executed before event handling is done component wise...

**But** its use is not generally recommended - it should be a very restricted use case, so.

Comment: I think that this is the way I will be going.  Not ideal, I agree.  I had hoped to avoid this call since it can be dangerous.  I am also using the garbage collection code as an example of keeping it tight (see the 3rd response below).

Answer (score 2):

The Eclipse IDE already has something similar to perform Garbage Collection, take a look at the class org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEIdleHelper in Bundle org.eclipse.ui.ide.application

Comment: Thanks - this class confirms what mtraut said above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that the `readAndDispatch` method will return false when there are no more messages to process. Something like this:

```
long lastActivityAt = 0;
int idleThresholdSecs = 5;
while (true)
{
    while (display.readAndDispatch())
    {
        lastActivityAt = System.nanoTime();
    }

    if (System.nanoTime() - lastActivityAt > idleThresholdSecs * 1000 * 1000 * 1000) 
    {
        // we have been idle for at least "idleThresholdSecs"
        ...
    } 
    else
    {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this. Did you already use this pattern? Question is if there are some "technical" events that are processed without real user interaction?

Comment: I haven't used it to detect idle-ness, but I have used it in cases where I need manually process events in the main thread without releasing control of it.